# How to remove everything after the last . from a text file content

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file called filename.txt which contains the long list of names with extension as follows:
I want to remove the extension, meaning everything after the last character .

```
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017.hdf
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033.hdf
AST006_S003.zip
AST003_S066.zip
```

I tried this command `awk '{print substr($0, 1, index($0, ".") - 1)}' filename.txt` but it removed everything after the first char .

```
MOR22A2
MOR22A2
AST006_S003
AST003_S066
```

I am looking to get something like below:

```
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033
AST006_S003
AST003_S066
```

I am using a bash script, how do I add the awk command in my bash script to modify the filename.txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would say that you can use a for loop to iterate and construct a new string by concatenating from each field then print that out.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} { s=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++){ s=s"."$i }; print s }' test.csv
```

input:

```
cat test.csv
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017.hdf
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033.hdf
```

output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} { s=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++){ s=s"."$i }; print s }' test.csv
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033
```

But you also have other options such as 1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234432/how-to-delete-the-last-column-of-a-file-in-linux/234436#234436

Based on the first link, you can try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="."} NF{NF-=1};1' test.csv
```

output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="."} NF{NF-=1};1' test.csv
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033
```

Comment: Changing the value of `NF` is undefined behavior, it'll do different things in different awks so you should say which version(s) of awk that'd work in (e.g. it'll do what you want in GNU awk).

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/, "")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a regular expression and apply '$' that will ensure that it only matches the end of the string, so your complete regex would be `/[.][^.]*$/` which means "fullstop+nofullstops+endofstring".

With `sed`, this would be:

```bash
   sed 's/[.][^.]*$//' < file.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me as expected, how can I achieve this using awk command ? I tried this but looks like the my syntax is not right 
awk 's/[.][^.]*$//' < filename.txt

Comment: There's varying regex support in awk. You will need to be more specific. Also, you may need to try Unix&Linux instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code using `match` function for this one.

```
awk 'match($0,/^.*\./){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `rev` and `cut` combination as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017.hdf
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033.hdf
AST006_S003.zip
AST003_S066.zip
```

then

```
rev file.txt | cut --delimiter='.' --fields=2- | rev
```

gives output

```
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v22.061.2023063111017
MOR22A2.S4000011.h23v44.061.2023061111033
AST006_S003
AST003_S066
```

Explanation: get mirror version of lines using `rev` then inform `cut` that it is dot-separated and select field 2nd and following (observe `-` after `2`) then again mirror lines to get original lines.